# Identify Two-Way Combinations of Levels in a Column for Each ID

Tags: r

I want to identify the two-way combinations of levels in one column grouped by the `id` and `Date` variables. Basically, I want the daily unique letter pairs for each person.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
in_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3), 
                    Date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01")), 
                    letter = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "D", "B")) 

in_df
  id       Date letter
1  1 2019-01-01      A
2  1 2019-01-01      B
3  1 2019-01-01      C
4  1 2019-01-02      A
5  1 2019-01-02      B
6  2 2019-01-01      A
7  2 2019-01-01      D
8  3 2019-01-01      B
```

And I want one that looks like this:

```
out_df
  id       Date letter_1 letter_2
1  1 2019-01-01        A        B
2  1 2019-01-01        A        C
3  1 2019-01-01        B        C
4  1 2019-01-02        A        B
5  2 2019-01-01        A        D
6  3 2019-01-01        B        NA
```

So the first `id` and the first `Date` have letters A, B, and C. I want every unique pair from the three. Order doesn't matter so switching what goes to `letter_1` and `letter_2` would be the same thing.

I have played around with `expand.grid` and `combn`, but neither seems quite appropriate for this task.

**EDIT**

I also have cases where there is only one row per `id`/`Date` so using combn gives me `Error in combn(letter, m = 2) : n < m`. How can I add an if case such that the `letter_2` gets an NA? (I also updated the dfs above to address this)

Comment: Can you please elaborate how was the second and third row in the output created? I mean the values in `letter_1` and `letter_2`.

Comment: @tmfmnk Thank you for the quick response! I tried clarifying a bit more, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table); setDT(in_df)

dt = in_df[, data.table(t(combn(letter, m = 2))), .(id, Date)]
```

Output:

```
> dt
   id       Date V1 V2
1:  1 2019-01-01  A  B
2:  1 2019-01-01  A  C
3:  1 2019-01-01  B  C
4:  1 2019-01-02  A  B
5:  2 2019-01-01  A  D
```

Comment: All the answers adequately answered my original question, but this was the only one I could get to work for my slightly more complicated actual data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` and `combn`:

```
do.call('rbind', 
        lapply(split(in_df, list(in_df$id, in_df$Date), drop = TRUE), 
               FUN = function(d) 
                 cbind.data.frame(unique(d[c('id', 'Date')]), 
                                  data.frame(t(
                                    if(length(d$letter) > 1){
                                      combn(d$letter, 2)    
                                    }else{
                                      matrix(c(d$letter, NA), nrow = 2)
                                    })))))


#                id       Date X1 X2
# 1.2019-01-01.1  1 2019-01-01  A  B
# 1.2019-01-01.2  1 2019-01-01  A  C
# 1.2019-01-01.3  1 2019-01-01  B  C
# 2.2019-01-01    2 2019-01-01  A  D
# 1.2019-01-02    1 2019-01-02  A  B
```

It might be helpful to step through this. Investigate the output of:

```
(ss <- split(in_df, list(in_df$id, in_df$Date), drop = TRUE))
```

Then check out:

```
lapply(ss, FUN = function(d) data.frame(t(combn(d$letter, 2))))
```

The rest of the way, we're just combining the data. You might want to adjust the column names a bit.

Comment: Thank you!! I also have cases where there is only one row per `id`/`Date` so when I use this answer, I get `Error in combn(letter, m = 2) : n < m`. How can I add in an if case such that the `letter_2` gets an NA?

Comment: see edit...it makes the code a bit more complicated, but it should handle your situation

Comment: It's been running for about an hour. Maybe my data is just too big for this method. This was really helpful though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code works:

```r
library("dplyr")
in_df %>% 
  group_by(id, Date) %>% 
  mutate(
    letter_1 = combn(letter, 2)[1, ],
    letter_2 = combn(letter, 2)[2, ]
  ) %>% 
  distinct(letter_1, letter_2)


# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# # Groups:   id, Date [3]
#   letter_1 letter_2    id Date      
#   <fct>    <fct>    <dbl> <date>    
# 1 A        B            1 2019-01-01
# 2 A        C            1 2019-01-01
# 3 B        C            1 2019-01-01
# 4 A        B            1 2019-01-02
# 5 A        D            2 2019-01-01
```